# $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] causing query UI not to load

Tags: php, jquery-ui, mobile

I'm having a strange problem.  When I use this code to detect a mobile device, its causing my query dialog to stop working (on iPhone only - not tested on other mobile devices), but it works fine in my browser. Is there a way around this?

```
<?php

  $iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
  $android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
  $palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
  $berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
  $ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
  $ipad = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");

  if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry || $ipad == true) 
     { 
       //do something
     } else { ?>
        <div id="scrollerWrapper">
          <div id="left_shopping_cart">
            <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/scripts/cart_side_products.php"); ?>
          </div>
        </div><!-- end#scrollerWrapper-->
        <?php 
      } ?>
```

If I take out the first block, query works fine on my iPhone.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Thank you.. no Its not my actual code. But I'll fix it for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is that `strpos()` is returning an integer but what you're asking it to return is a `boolean` value.

From: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

> strpos
>
> (PHP 4, PHP 5)
>   strpos — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string
>
> Description
>
> mixed strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
>   Find the numeric position of the first occurrence of needle in the haystack string.

Also, for this part:

```
if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry || $ipad == true)
```

you have some syntax errors in your if conditions. These should written as:

```
if ($iphone == [target value] || $android == [target value] || $palmpre == [target value] ... // and so on for each`
```

There's also something special to note about `strpos()`: It will return `0` (i.e. `int`) if the search value is located at the starting position in the string, and it will return `FALSE` (i.e. `boolean`) if the target substring is not found in the string at all.

Basically, the correct code you are looking for would be something like this:

```
<?php
$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$ipad = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");

if ( $iphone !== FALSE 
     || $android !== FALSE 
     || $palmpre !== FALSE 
     || $ipod !== FALSE 
     || $berry !== FALSE 
     || $ipad !== FALSE ) { 

       //do something

} else {
    ?>
    <div id="scrollerWrapper">
        <div id="left_shopping_cart">
            <?php
            include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/scripts/cart_side_products.php"); 
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end#scrollerWrapper-->
<?php 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Although your solution is a lot cleaner, I found out that I had a javascript error. Apparently when I omitted the div, my javascript was giving an error causing the query dialog to not function correctly. +1 for helping

Answer (score 0):

As DrewT points out, your code has a typing error. Boolean FALSE is not exactly the same as zero, and it is also not exactly the same as NULL. You also are relying on $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], which is not actually guaranteed to be available - and should not be trusted even if it is (e.g. my normal browser always identifies itself as Windows Firefox, although that is not my operating system or my browser.)

Here is a method which first checks if the [HTTP_USER_AGENT](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) is set, then uses [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to check if the user agent string matches one of the platforms for which you are looking. (The specific platform name is captured in the array element `$matches[1][0]`, and the offset within the user agent string is captured in `$matches[1][1]`.)

```
if ( array_key_exists( 'HTTP_USER_AGENT', $_SERVER ) &&
    isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT' ) ){
    $matches = array();

    // preg_match returns 1 if matched, 0 if not found, or FALSE if error.
    if( preg_match( '/([iPhone|Android|webOS|BlackBerry|iPod|iPad])/i',
        $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE ) == 1 ){
        // do something
    }else{
        // do something else 
    }
}
```